# ReferenceError: data is not defined or 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

and thank you in advance for reading this. I'm new in php and jquery. I've managed to do few forms in php that worked, and now feel a big need (because of how my webpage is shaping) to make them work with jquery. I'm trying but something is not right. This is the form:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method ="post" id="form_Add">
<br>
<div class="Add_field" id="title_div">Title:<input typee="text" class="Add_text" maxlength="100" name="title" id="title"></div>
<br>
<div class="Add_field">Discription:<input typee="text" class="Add_text" maxlength="1000" name="discription" id="discription"></div>
<br>
<div class="Add_field" id="content_div">Content:<textarea class="Add_text" maxlength="65535" name="content" id="content" rows="5" cols="15"></textarea></div>
<br>
<div class="Add_field"><label for="shortstory"><input typee="radio" name="prose" class="" id="shortstory" value="1">Short story</label></div>
<div class="Add_field" id="prose_div"><label for="chapter"><input typee="radio" name="prose" class="" id="chapter" value="2">Chapter</label></div>
<br>
<div class="Add_field" id="typey">type:
<select name="type1">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">Fantasy</option>
    <option value="2">Action</option>
    <option value="3">Romance</option>
</select>with elements of 
<select name="type2" id="type2">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">fantasy</option>
    <option value="2">action</option>
    <option value="3">romance</option>
</select>and
<select name="type3" id="type3">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1">fantasy</option>
    <option value="2">action</option>
    <option value="3">romance</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="Add_field"><input typee="submit" name="Add_story" class="Add_button" id="submit_story" value="Add story"></div>
</form>

<div id="response">Something</div>
```

That is script:

```
<script>



$('#form_Add').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            checkAdd(); 
            });

var selectType = function(){
    var type2 = $('#type2').val();  
    if(type2 === ""){
        $('#type3').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#type3').val("");
    }
    else{
        $('#type3').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
}

$(selectType);
$("#type2").change(selectType);


function checkAdd(){
    var title = $('#title').val();
    var content = $('#content').val();
    if(title === ""){
        $('#titleErr').remove();
        $('#title_div').append("<p id='titleErr'>Please add the title.</p>");
    }
    else{
        $('#titleErr').remove();    
    }
    if(content.replace(/ /g,'').length <= 18){
        $('#contentErr').remove();
        $('#content_div').append("<p id='contentErr'>Content needs to be at least 19 characters long.</p>");
    }
    else{
        $('#contentErr').remove();  
    }
    if($("#shortstory").not(":checked") && $("#chapter").not(":checked")){
        $('#proseErr').remove();
        $('#prose_div').append("<p id='proseErr'>Check one of the above.</p>");
    }
    if($("#shortstory").is(":checked") || $("#chapter").is(":checked")){
        $('#proseErr').remove();    
    }
    if($("#titleErr").length == 0 && $("#contentErr").length == 0 && $("#proseErr").length == 0){

         $.post('"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"', {  // when using this bit of script I get 403 Forbidden in Firebug console
            title: $('#title').val(),
            discription: $('#discription').val(),
            content: $('#content').val(),
            prose: $('input[name=prose]:checked').val(),
            type1: $('#type1').val(),
            type2: $('#type2').val(),
            type3: $('#type3').val()
        }, function(d){

            alert(d);
            console.log(d);
            $('#response').html(d);
            });


    }
    /*

    var postData = $("#form_Add").serialize();       // when using this bit of script instead of one on top, I get alert fail and ReferenceError: data is not defined in Firebug console
    var formURL = $("#form_Add").attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        typee: "POST",
        data : postData,
        datatypee: 'json',
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            alert("success");//data: return data from server 
            console.log(data.error);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails     
            alert("fail");
            console.log(data.error);

        }
    });
    }
*/
};


</script>
```

And here is php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
 if(isset ($_SESSION['arr'])){
$arr = $_SESSION['arr']; 
$uid = $arr['id'];
}
$title = $discription = $content = $prose ="";

if (isset($_POST["Add_story"])) {

        $title = stripslashes($_POST["title"]);
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $title);


        $discription = stripslashes($_POST["discription"]);
        $discription = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $discription);   


        $content = stripslashes($_POST["content"]);
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $content);


        $prose = stripslashes($_POST["prose"]);
        $prose = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection , $prose);


        $type1 = $_POST["type1"];
        $type2 = $_POST["type2"];
        $type3 = $_POST["type3"];


        $pQuery = "INSERT INTO  prose (u_id, data, title_s, discription_s, content_s, prose_s, type1_s, type2_s, type3_s, shows_s)
        VALUES ('{$uid}', CURDATE(), '{$title}', '{$discription}', '{$content}', {$prose}, '{$type1}', '{$type2}', '{$type3}', 0)";
        $resultP = mysqli_query($connection, $pQuery);

            if ($resultP) {


                $title = $discription = $content = $prose ="";

            } 
            else {

                die("Query failed." . mysqli_error($connection));

            }

}
?>
```

Php code is on the top of the document. Source is on bottom and form is in the middle (I'm using jquery-1.11.1.min.js - source is added in main page, as this one is included in it). I've also tried putting php in separate file and pointing to it through form action instead of `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` but without any joy. I'm guessing my problem is with post data. It probably has to be in an array or object (and I'm doing it wrong) and when it reaches processing there is some sort of incompatibility. Probably using select and radio buttons complicates the process.

Any tips you can share I will greatly appreciate. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a serious typo in your submit button

```
<input typee="submit" name="Add_story"
           ^ extra "e"
```

which should read as

```
<input type="submit" name="Add_story"
```

Your code's execution relies on your conditional statement:

```
if (isset($_POST["Add_story"])){...}
```

Plus, you've made the same typo for all your other inputs `typee="xxx"`

- Change them all to `type`

A simple CTRL-H (typee/type) in a code editor such as Notepad++ even in Notepad will fix that in a jiffy.

---

I noticed you have given id's to both `<select name="type2" id="type2">`
and `<select name="type3" id="type3">` but not for `<select name="type1">`, so that could also be another factor that could affect your code's execution, seeing that you have:

```
type1: $('#type1').val(),
type2: $('#type2').val(),
type3: $('#type3').val()
```

---

**Edit:**

You've also put a commented message which I only saw now and should have been made clear in your question:

```
// when using this bit of script I get 403 Forbidden in Firebug console
```

over to the right of

```
$.post('"<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"', {
```

so I didn't see that.

Try changing it to either, and in single quotes only:

```
$.post('<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>', {
```

or

```
$.post('your_file.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
```

This page may help:

- **https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/jquery-ajax-post-example.html**

It contains an example in there that you can base yourself on.

which contains

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'post_receiver.php', 
            data: $(this).serialize()
        })
```

and may need to be added to your script.

You commented out `url : formURL,` - try using `url: 'your_PHP_file.php',` in its place, that being the PHP/SQL file that you're using.

- If none of this helped, than let me know and I will simply delete this answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Fred -ii-. You've helped a lot. Double quotes in $.post url and relying on $_POST["Add_story"] were the problem. Typee was not the case as just happened on translating peaces of code (it was late at night ;-)) in notepad++ using find/replace caused it ;-) Thanks a million.

Comment: @aya9 You're most welcome. I had to make sure about the typos. I'm glad to hear that the problem was solved, *cheers*